# The Network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password

Tags: windows, windows-7, network-share, network-attached-storage, readynas

I have a NAS device, it has 3 shares. On one computer I have access to all 3 of the shares. On another computer I keep getting this error when  try and add a 2nd one.

```
The Network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password [...]
```

That is the message I keep getting. What causes that?

EDIT: 
Every share has it's own username and password.

EDIT: NET USE on the one running 3 from the same NAS device

```
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           T:        \\192.168.2.5\SHARE1      Microsoft Windows Network
OK           X:        \\Nas-1dsho-abc\SHARE2    Microsoft Windows Network
Disconnected Y:        \\192.168.2.9\backups     Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Z:        \\Nas-1dsho-abc\cbackups  Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

NET USE on the other:

```
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Y:        \\192.168.2.5\SHARE1  Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  Z:        \\192.168.2.5\SHARE2    Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

EDIT:

I have been using the 'connect using different credentials' option.

Comment: Perhaps the network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password :-). What does `NET USE` show?

Comment: What share is the one that is giving the error? Does this error come up after a reboot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NET USE` does not allow you to connect to the same server with different credentials. This is because it reuses the same relationship to map additional shares on the same server. You can work around this by making windows think it's a different server either by creating DNS aliases for the same NAS with different names or editing the hosts file on the clients.

A better solution would be to change your account structure. Don't create an account on the NAS for each share. Create an account on the NAS for each client and give those accounts permissions to the shares.

Comment: There's an official support page https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/cannot-connect-to-network-share#workaround-1
 that gives another workaround of using the IP address directly

Answer (score 6):

If the share is mapped under a **different user**, you get that message. The mapping is unavailable (to you), and you can't get it to go away.  So

1. switch to the other user;
2. unmap the drive in Windows explorer;
3. run "control userpasswords2", Advanced tab, Manage Passwords, Windows Credentials, and remove the login (for good measure);
4. reboot;
5. try again under your login.

Comment: You can also do *net use sharename /delete* if you don't want to change account

Comment: It is possible to remove the share as @David suggested even if you do not have access to Windows Credentials section in control panel (e.g. when it's disabled by group policy).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have to be the *same* network folder that's mapped. It could be a different folder on the same server, a *subfolder* of the folder already mapped (which qualifies as my first guess). Not sure how you pulled it off on the first machine, but the best course of action is to check the box that say 'connect using different credentials'. There is an answer already [here](https://superuser.com/questions/123833/how-do-i-change-the-user-i-am-logged-in-with-on-a-network-share), no screenshots though as they are command line answers, but effective nonetheless.

Comment: Yea, I have been using the connect using different credentials option ;/

Comment: You can check what accounts Windows is using to connect to remote shares by doing Start>Run>**control userpasswords2**. Switch to the Advanced tab then click Manage Passwords, then select Windows Credentials and look for the resource you're trying to connect to. Windows won't let you connect to the same server with different credentials. I'd double check on how you're connected to Nas-1dsho-abc from the first computer, I'd wager it's the same credentials for both connections.

Answer (score 0):

An app I just released on the Windows store called "Advanced share mapper" will do just this.

You can:

1. Connect to the same share on a server with different sets of credentials OR
2. Map to different shares on the same server with different sets of credentials.