# "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user" when there are no connections

Tags: windows, network-share, network-attached-storage, windows-10, net-use

Related to: [The Network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password](https://serverfault.com/questions/549289/the-network-folder-specified-is-currently-mapped-using-a-different-user-name-and)

However, I am not currently connected to the network location already.

I if type `net use` I get the following output:

```
>net use
New connections will not be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.
```

And when I go to map the drive it asks for the credentials twice, then on the 2nd time fails with the message:

> The network folder specified is currently mapped using a different
>   user name and password.

If I try and map it via `net use` in the console I get:

```
net use z: \\[location]\Data /user:[username] [password]
System error 1219 has occurred.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.
```

There are no connections, yet when I try and map the drive it fails as if there are.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain what this question needs to be more clear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out windows had cached credentials for this location.

Go to `Control Panel > Credentials Manager`

Under `Windows Credentials`

[image]

Remove the account that has cached credentials to the network share. Try and remap drive now.

Failing that you can try:

```
net stop workstation /y
net start workstation
```

Comment: I needed both delete credentials + restart workstation